# animate package compilation error after upgrade to version 40001

Tags: beamer, animate

After upgrading **animate** package to its last version (40001), a document which is compiled using version 39907 fails to compile.

The compilation gives a lot of error being the first

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. \end{frame}
```

When using other computer with version 39907, document compiles with no error.

Any clue?

Comment: I have reported that bug to the maintainer yesterday. To narrow down what is going on, I have found that this seems to only happen with the beamer class when compiling with pdflatex or lualatex. using another class like article to the koma equivalent works fine. compiling the beamer document with xelatex also works for me.

Comment: A fixed version `[2016/03/15]` is already on the way to CTAN. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: Thanks @AlexG, Just tested the new version now and every thing works fine!

Comment: actually, @jose-palma, although you seem to be using beamer (`\end{frame}` in your error message) the error is in fact different than the one I got, and therefore may not have been fixed byAlexG in his latest update. Could you provide more information in the form or a mwe so that we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: @ArTourter : A stack size error occured when e. g. the `amsmath` package was loaded together with the pre-`[2016/03/15]` version of `animate`. This error does in fact not occur any more  after yesterday's update.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your quick response. The first solution was to downgrade animate version to my last back-up and all works fine again (I needed it quickly for a lecture in the same day ;-). I have been trying to upgrade to the last version but my package manager tool (MacTex 2015) is getting the version causing the error. I will try to upgrade manually and test it.

Comment: Finally, I have just tested version 40030 in my document and compilation error has disappeared. Thank you

Comment: Perhaps, we can close the question now?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is about a bug that can be resolved by a package update of the local installation.